# Is there a way to parse this JSON?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a JSON of following format,
`{
   "A.B.C" : "a.b.c",
   "C.D.E" : "c.d.e"
}`
but I'm unable to parse this json in javascript.How can I get the value of "A.B.C"?

And I want to load this JSON in the content[] of Ember.ResourceController using load() in ember-rest.js

while loading this i got an error "Object in path A.B could not be found or was destroyed"

Comment: "unable to parse" why? How you try? What error you get?

Comment: Read about [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Comment: Did you try any thing at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), that JSON is valid, which means you can parse it regularly:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "A.B.C" : "a.b.c", "C.D.E" : "c.d.e" }');
var test = obj["A.B.C"]; // "a.b.c"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88vFv/

The trick is you need to use bracket notation instead of dot notation, since your property names contain dots.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var json = { "A.B.C" : "a.b.c", "C.D.E" : "c.d.e" };
var value = json["A.B.C"];
```

Answer (score 1):

DId you try this?

```
data = JSON.parse('{ "A.B.C" : "a.b.c", "C.D.E" : "c.d.e" }')
data["A.B.C"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `JSON.parse`:

```
var values = JSON.parse('{ "A.B.C" : "a.b.c", "C.D.E" : "c.d.e" }');
var result = values['A.B.C'];
```